# Why I cannot switch into given mode "develop"?

Tags: magento2, deploy, developer-mode

I use this basic environment [Docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/rafaelcgstz/magento2/), with Magento 2.1. When I was tried to change the **deploy mode**, the terminal shows me:

> Cannot switch into given mode "develop"

The permission's ok, and I had tried with **bin/magento** and **magerun2**.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's because the mode is called **developer**, not **develop**

Comment: science be praised